# Error resolving drawable resources in Android API Level 3

Tags: android

I'm developing an application that uses tabs and should be compatible with Android 1.5 (API Level 3).

Please see [Tab icons compatibility between API level 3 and >=5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801443/tab-icons-compatibility-between-api-level-3-and-5). Basically I have two sets of tab icons as google recommends.

- Tab icons for targets >= 5 are located in drawable-(h/m/l)dpi-v5.
- Tab icons for targets < 5 and all other drawable resources are located in drawable-(h/m/l)dpi.
- My AndroidManifest.xml has `android:minSdkVersion="3"` and `android:targetSdkVersion="5"`.
- I'm compiling using Level 7 SDK
- All my code is Level 3 compatible

When running in a device/emulator >= Level 5 everything works correctly, tab icons are displayed ok using the -v5 resources. In a device Level 4 everything also works ok, tab icons are also ok.

However, when using a device level 3 the app crashes when trying to resolve a drawable resource. The stack says something like this:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable/splash_background.xml
       at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
       at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:471)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1825)
```

Note that `res/drawable/splash_background.xml` exists. This is one example, it throws the same error when trying to fetch any drawable resource.

Any clues on this?

Comment: Does splash_background.xml refer to any other drawables? Perhaps one that only exists in a -v5 resource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The -ldpi, -hdpi and -mdpi qualifiers were added in API 4, so they don't work.

See [Providing screen resource compatibility for Android 1.5](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ScreenCompatibility).

Comment: Wow thanks, I wasn't aware that (h/m/l)dpi was introduced in API 4. So basically I need to move everything from drawable-mdpi to drawable.

Comment: @aromero you're welcome. I think I knew that only because I've read some "old" book. These APIs are evolving fast.

Comment: Took me three hours to figure that problem out.  Wish I'd seen your answer much sooner.  Thanks, bigs!